# join two tables using laravel 8 , without id

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following two tables in database :

[image] [image]

I have the following view :

```
<div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <label>Pays</label>
                       <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="pays" id="pays">
                         <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                         @foreach($countries as $country)
                         <option value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                       </select>
                   </div>

                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <label>Ville</label>
                       <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="ville" id="ville">
                       </select>
                   </div>
              </div>
```

My Controller :

```
public function getAllStates()
    {
        $country_id = request('country');

        $states = State::where('country_id',$country_id)->get();

                
                $option = "<option value = ''> Select State</option>";


        foreach($states as $state){
            $option.= '<option value = "'.$state->name.'">'.$state->name.'</option>';
        }
        return $option;
    }
```

My script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $("#pays").change(function(){
           let country_id = this.value;
           $.get('/getState?country='+country_id,function(data){
              $("#ville").html(data);
           });
       });

  });

</script>
```

I want to get in the second dropdown all the states associates with a country.

so in my drop-down country, I passed to value a country name and note a country id, how can I join the two tables to get all state's names of a country with the country names and not country IDs?

Comment: Are you meant to have `$country->name` as the value of the option element, or `country->id`? `<option value="{{$country->name}}">`

Comment: I meant <option value="{{$country->name}}"> , how can  I get all the stats of a country while I have country_id in the state table

Comment: With `<option value="{{$country->name}}">`, the line `let country_id = this.value;` means that `country_id` will be `$country->name`.

Comment: yes, so how can I in my controller get the country id for getting the states name

Comment: in this line :  $states = State::where('country_id',$country_id)->get();

Comment: Your problem is in the controller, `$country_id` will have the name of the country, not the id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233735/discussion-between-ha-jar-and-will-walsh).

Comment: why not keep data-attribute inside option tag with value of id i.e : `<option  data-id="{{$country->id}}" value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>` Then inside your event handler get this id using `$(this).find("option:selected").data("id")` ?

Comment: @Swati , thank you for your help, it works for me, but I don't get the states associated with a country, like my route isn't set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML needs to change so the country id is the value selected by the option elements.

```
@foreach($countries as $country)
  <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Then the controller should work as expected and return the states that have that country id, but keep in mind, you should use `$state->id` as the value of the option element once more.

```
foreach($states as $state) {
  $option .= '<option value = "'.$state->id.'">'.$state->name.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but I want in value ; value="{{$country->name}}"